# how to detect if user has an app in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

How can I detect if user has an app, like echofon or twitter for mac or if user has pages, or textmate? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use NSWorkspace's fullPathForApplication: to get an application's bundle path. If that method returns nil, the app is not installed. For example:

```
NSString *path = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] fullPathForApplication:@"Twitter"];

BOOL isTwitterInstalled = (nil != path);
```

URLForApplicationWithBundleIdentifier is another method you may use.

Answer (score -2):

I have never tried the code in the above answer, but the following works for me:

```
    if ( [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"app-scheme://"]] ) {
        NSLog(@"This app is installed.");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"This app is not installed.");
    }
```

This method requires the app to have a scheme though. I don't know about the one above.

Comment: Hey buddy.  Based on his tags, Rafa looks like he was actually asking about the Mac platform, not the iPhone platform.

Comment: also thanks I will need make an iphone version... so thank you very much

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the tags. I'm a new poster (I have read other posts before to help me with my problems but never actually posted) here at Stackoverflow.