# How to use canOpenURL in mac OS application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

I had a function to check if chrome could be open an url. In iOS I had:

```
// is chrome installed??
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"googlechrome://"]])
    {
     ...
     }
```

But now in my app to Mac OS, I can't use this, because is undeclared function with NSWorkspace.

```
if ([[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"googlechrome://"]])
    {
     ...
     }
```

So, how can use canOpenURL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `NSWorkspace`'s `fullPathForApplication` to get an application's bundle path. If that method returns `nil`, the app is not installed.

Related question: [how to detect if user has an app in Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866273/how-to-detect-if-user-has-an-app-in-cocoa)